# Postgres update rule returning number of rows affected

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a view table which is a union of two separate tables (say Table _A and Table _B).

I need to be able to update a row in the view table, and it seems the way to do this was through a 'view rule'.  All entries in the view table have separate id's, so an id that exists in table _A won't exist in table _B.

I created the following rule:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE view_update AS
    ON UPDATE TO viewtable DO INSTEAD ( UPDATE _A SET foo = false
  WHERE old.id = _A.id;
 UPDATE _B SET foo = false
  WHERE old.id = _B.id;
);
```

If I do an update on table _B it returns the correct number of rows affected (1).  However if I update table _A it returns (0) rows affected even though the data was changed.  If I swap out the order of the updates then the same thing happens, but in reverse.

How can I solve this problem so that it returns the correct number of rows affected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Unless you do it in a stored procedure and return the number of affected rows.

A good explanation in the official [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-triggers.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. There is no way for PostgreSQL to know via a rule. Further, rules are slow. You really should consider a trigger instead.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [Section 39.6. Rules and Command Status](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/rules-status.html)

> If there is any unconditional INSTEAD rule for the query, then the original query will not be executed at all. In this case, **the server will return the command status for the last query** that was inserted by an INSTEAD rule (conditional or unconditional) and is **of the same command type** (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE) **as the original query. If no query meeting those requirements is added by any rule, then the returned command status shows the original query type and zeroes for the row-count and OID fields.**

In my case I was able to work around by exposing the relation using a view and a `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view.